# find prev() sibling() jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to target closest prev Tr with its child Tr's. My table is like this :

```
<table>
    <tr class="parent">
        <td>Apple</td>
        <td>Orange</td>
        <td>Banana</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="child">
        <td>Apple 1</td>
        <td>Orange 1</td>
        <td>Banana 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="child">
        <td>Apple 2</td>
        <td>Orange 2</td>
        <td>Banana 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="parent">
        <td>Table</td>
        <td>cHAIR</td>
        <td>Mouse</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="child">
        <td>Table 1</td>
        <td>cHAIR 1</td>
        <td>Mouse 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="child">
        <td>Table 2</td>
        <td>cHAIR 2</td>
        <td>Mouse 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Is that possible to target parent tr with it's child tr using `closest()+prev()` or `siblings()+prev()` ?

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense. The `TR`s don't have child `TR`s, they have child `TD`s.

Comment: What is the current element you're starting from, and which elements are you trying to select from it?

Answer (score 2):

One hack that comes to mind is

```
var parents = $('.parent');
$('.child').each(function () {
    var tr = this
    var p = $(tr).prevAll(parents).first()[0];
    console.log(tr, p)
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/yejKL/)

Comment: but when I try to write : $(p).css({ background: 'red'}); it makes parent and first child row's bg red.

Comment: its working when i used there: 
var p = $(tr).prevAll('.parent').eq(0); thanks for idea.

Answer (score 2):

It'll work

```
$(this).parent("tr").prev('tr.parent');
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [next siblings selector](http://api.jquery.com/next-siblings-selector/) :
you can combine many selector by `~` or `+`

`$($(tr).prev() + $(prev).find('*'))`

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can do that this way:

```
$(this).parent("tr").sibling();
```

Or to select previous all siblings:

```
$(this).parent("tr").prevAll("tr");
```

Instead to select all the next ones:

```
$(this).parent("tr").nextAll("tr");
```